# Formatting done on table in C# is not visible in pdf generated using itextsharp

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext

Formatting done on table in C# is not visible in pdf generated using itextsharp.

I am doing formatting as below:

```
Table table = new Table();
table.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
table.Style.Add("width", "696");
table.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
TableRow row = new TableRow();
TableCell cell = new TableCell();
cell.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
Unit ut = new Unit(2);
cell.BorderWidth = ut;
cell.BorderColor = Color.Black;
```

But still my pdf is generated without any formatting.
My table is shown in pdf. however no formatting is applied.

Any idea?

Comment: I don't see any iTextSharp in your code.

Comment: Is this an ASP.Net `Table` or an iTextSharp `Table`? If the latter, please make sure to use `PdfPTable` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you like to add a black border and set the table width to 696.

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
table.TotalWidth = 696f;
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Hello World!", new Font(Font.ARIAL, 12f, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
cell.BorderColor = new Color(0,0,0);
cell.Border = Rectangle.LEFT_BORDER | Rectangle.RIGHT_BORDER;
cell.BorderWidthLeft = 2f;
cell.BorderWidthRight = 2f;
table.AddCell(cell);
```